# Can I use 2x6 rafters for my garage roof?

Tags: load-bearing, roofing, rafter

I plan to build a 24ft x 30ft garage (28ft x 34ft with 2ft overhangs). I was planning on using 2x8 rafters, but I'm wondering if I can get away with using 2x6 rafters instead. The rafters are 24 inches on center and supported by two structural beams (LVL) spaced at 8 feet from the outside walls.

The beams are running the 30 foot length, supported by one column in the center of each beam (15ft from the outside walls)  and obviously the beams also being supported by the outside walls.

The rafters will run the 28ft length spanning a 2ft overhang supported by the outside wall continuing 8ft to the first beam, then continuing another 8ft supported by the second beam, then another 8ft supported by the outside wall, and then a final 2ft for the overhang.

I was wondering if this can be done within current building codes first and secondly would the have a sufficient Load strength?  I am in Northern New York for climate info. I know 2x8 rafters or even 2x10 rafters would be just fine but since I'm only actually spanning 8ft with the rafters could 2x6s be used for cost reduction purposes?

[image]

Comment: I would check with your local building department.  I am just north of there and know some small local areas get dumped on with feet of snow and a few miles down the road get an inch.

Comment: How much savings are you expecting? Locally, a x8 is only $1-$2 more per board than x6. Considering you are in a potentially massive snowfall territory (https://www.weather.gov/source/erh/probSnow/nohrsc.png), it hardly seems worth a risk of re-doing the roof in an emergency to save $50...

Comment: Thanks for the  responses guys!  If the price difference was only a couple dollars each I wouldn't worry about saving a few bucks,  but locally the price difference between 2x6 and 2x8 are just over 7$ to make matters worse this project is coming out of pocket so I'm just trying to save where I can but still meet load strengths.  I'm not rich, Call me cheap lol

Comment: Where I am located  I like to call the Bermuda triangle for snow.  15 min from the Canadian border and wouldn't be unusual to get a snowfall a couple times a season of 2 feet overnight, and 5 miles away to only get 6 inches lol